# can we add functions as props to each item in array.map(item,index)

Tags: reactjs

i'm kinda new to React Js and i'm trying to map the array of components.
and i need to bind a function to each component then call that function inside of each component using props.

```js
// main component
array1 = [<component1> , <component2> , <component3> , <component4>];

// other compoenent
this.state = this.props.array1;

{this.state.map( (item, index)=> {
  {item} // bind function here
})}
```

if these components are in the same component as i need.
i cloud do this:

```js
handleNext() {
  // do stuff
}

<component next={this.handleNext.bind(this}>
```

but i can not add next as props into items in array.map .
somehow i want to do this:

```js
handleNext() {
  // do stuff
}

{this.state.map( (item, index)=> {
  {item next={this.handleNext.bind(this)} // bind function here
})}
```

if you guys know any solution that can help me with this.
i will be Glad.

Comment: You have mis matching brackets `bind(this}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in two ways. Use `React.CloneElement` and then add the new props or you can use components from an array and then pass new props. The two solutions are included in this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/3kvok39pn1

Comment: thanks a lot - it's woking but when i call the doSomething like this
this.props.doSomething from one that components i get this error

Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `nativeEvent` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().

Comment: The `doSomething` function was only an example and I didn't check if it works fine. I showed only the way how you can pass the data and solve your problem :)